# How to sort imageio glob frames numerically

Tags: python, animation, frame, glob

I want to sort the frames so that it first is 0.png, 1.png, 2.png, 3.png etc

**My code:**

```py
# Getting all the frames and saving them in array
image_path = Path('frames')
images = sorted(list(image_path.glob('*.png')))
image_list = []
for file_name in images:
    print(f"Got {file_name}")
    image_list.append(imageio.imread(file_name))


# Main Code
imageio.mimwrite('test.gif', image_list, format='GIF', fps=100, duration=0.2)
```

**I have a folder in my directory called frames where multiple frames are stored like 0.png 1.png, 2.png etc**

I want to sort them so that I can have a valid gif

Answer (score 0):

You can just count how many png files you have and then add them to the list

```
list = []
frameCount = len(glob.glob1(frames_path,"*.png"))
for i in range(0, frameCount):
    list.append(imageio.imread(frames_path + "/" + str(i) + ".png"))
    print("added " + str(i) + ".png")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

So if you use `pathlib`:

```
image_path = Path('frames')
images = sorted(
    list(image_path.glob('*.png')),
    key=lambda f: int(f.stem)
)
```

There is also a nice library called **`natsort`** to do natural sorting:
[natsort](https://natsort.readthedocs.io/en/master/)